# Cloudify monitoring and Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, cloudify

I use Cloudify 2.7.0 GA and I bootstrapped cloudify on Openstack Havana.

How to integrate cloudify monitoring and Zabbix?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the REST API to get Cloudify metrics:

```
/{version}/deployments/{appName}/service/{serviceName}/instances/{instanceId}/metrics
```

See the [corresponding entry on the REST API docs](http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/restapi/restdoclet.html#REST_API-/%7Bversion%7D/deployments/%7BappName%7D/service/%7BserviceName%7D/instances/%7BinstanceId%7D/metrics).

Comment: Is there a list of monitoring metrics type "Server Uptime",     "Client Connections","Total Queries","Slow Queries"...

Answer (score 0):

I would use curl to get metrics from management interface and zabbix_trapper to send them zabbix server.
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper

I didn't use api before but if there is an api to expose metrics, it would be proper method.